# How do I simplify this piece of React code? (Progressive input form)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

The purpose of the sample of React code below is to create progressive form which only displays one question to begin with and then reveals the next question when the user clicks a button (while keeping the previous questions visible). The actual piece of code I've written contains 12 questions - the number, content and order of which could change over time.  Currently the code works but it's very long and difficult to update and so I'm sure there must be a better more dynamic way of doing this.  One way I've experimented with is having a sperate .js file containing an array of variables for each question but I've not been able to keep the "progressive" aspect of the form working with is method.

Any thoughts or advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import classes from './InputForm2.module.css';

const InputForm2 = () => {
  const dateOfBirthInputRef = useRef();
  const membershipTypeInputRef = useRef();
  const dateOfJoiningInputRef = useRef();

  let navigate = useNavigate();
  function routeChange() {
    let path = '/results';
    navigate(path);
  }

  function dataHandler() {
    const enteredDateofBirth = dateOfBirthInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredMembershipType = membershipTypeInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredDateOfJoining = dateOfJoiningInputRef.current.value;

    const inputData = {
      dateOfBirth: enteredDateofBirth,
      membershipType: membershipTypeRef,
      dateOfJoining: enteredDateOfJoining,
    };
    console.log(inputData);
  }

  function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    dataHandler();
    routeChange();
  }

  const [q2IsOpen, setQ2IsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [q3IsOpen, setQ3IsOpen] = useState(false);

  const btn1ClickHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setQ2IsOpen(true);
  };

  const btn2ClickHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setQ3IsOpen(true);
  };

  const btn3ClickHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setQ4IsOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.formbox}>
      <form>
        <section className={`${classes.active}`}>
          <div className={classes.textbox}>
            <b>Question 1</b>
            <p>What is your date of birth?</p>
            <input
              className={classes.input}
              type="date"
              required
              ref="dateOfBirthInputRef"
            ></input>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.btn__container}>
            <button className={classes.button} onClick={btn1ClickHandler}>
              Next
            </button>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section className={`${q2IsOpen ? classes.active : classes.inactive}`}>
          <div className={classes.textbox}>
            <b>Question 2</b>
            <p>
              What is your membershiptype?
            </p>
            <select
              className={classes.input}
              required
              ref="membershipTypeInputRef"
            >
              <option></option>
              <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
              <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
              <option value="Basic">Basic</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.btn__container}>
            <button className={classes.button} onClick={btn2ClickHandler}>
              Next
            </button>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section className={`${q3IsOpen ? classes.active : classes.inactive}`}>
          <div className={classes.textbox}>
            <b>Question 3</b>
            <p>What date did you start your membership?</p>
            <input
              className={classes.input}
              type="date"
              required
              ref="dateOfJoiningInputRef"
            ></input>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.btn__container}>
            <button className={classes.button} onClick={btn3ClickHandler}>
              Next
            </button>
          </div>
        </section>

        <div className={classes.btn__container}>
          <button
            className={`${classes.submitbutton} ${
              q4IsOpen ? classes.active : classes.inactive
            }`}
            onClick={submitHandler}
          >
            Calculate
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputForm2;
```

Comment: Have you thought of creating another component which just shows the question? You can use props of this component to make the question active or inactive. Put the questions in an array, and only render the one which is active.

Comment: I actually need to keep the questions which have already appeared visible to the user

Comment: You can do that, maybe use css styling to gray out the questions which have already been displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't fully working code, just an idea of how you would structure this. As you suggested yourself, making an array of question objects is a good idea. You could also break out the question structure into it's own component:

```
const Question = ({thisIndex, currentIndex, title, text, ref, handler}) => {
        
    return(
        <section className={`${thisIndex >= currentIndex-1 ? classes.active : classes.inactive}`}>
              <div className={classes.textbox}>
                <b>{title}</b>
                <p>{text}</p>
                <input
                  className={classes.input}
                  type="date"
                  required
                  ref=ref
                ></input>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.btn__container}>
                <button className={classes.button} onClick={handler}>
                  Next
                </button>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

The props input to `Question` component can be mapped from a `QUESTIONS` object array, assuming an object structure like `{title: 'Question 1', text: 'Why are we here?', //and so on}`.
I would keep track of visibility simply by keeping track of the index of the last answered question in the main form, and passing that in to each question in the array - that way it only becomes visible when the question before is answered.

```
const InputForm2 = () => {
    
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
    
    //all your other code
    
    const handler = (i) => {
        setCurrentIndex(i)
        //do more stuff
    }
    
    const questions = QUESTIONS.map((question, i) => {
        return(
            <Question key={i} 
                thisIndex=i currentIndex={currentIndex}
                title={question.title} text={question.text}
                handler={handler(i)}
                //and so on
            />
        )
    });

    return (
        <div>{questions}</div>
    )
}
```

Then, in your form you can return the `questions` array of components.

EDIT

In a similar way, since you have different types of input / select for different questions, you can make separate components and pass those as props to you question.

```
const QSelector = ({options}) => {
   const optionElements = options.map((option, i) => {
    return(
        <option //get your data from option element
    )
})
   return(
        <selector>
           {options}
        </selector>
   )
}
```

Obviously for three different input types and three questions, this isn't super useful but as you go in, if you have 5 selector q's, 5 inputs, you'll find you can reuse a lot of structures, just passing in any data that is different.

Below, I'm updating the Question component to receive this as an 'answer' prop.

```
const Question = ({thisIndex, currentIndex, title, text, ref, handler, answer}) => {

return(
    <section className={`${thisIndex >= currentIndex-1 ? classes.active : classes.inactive}`}>
          <div className={classes.textbox}>
            <b>{title}</b>
            <p>{text}</p>
            {answer}
        </div>
        <div className={classes.btn__container}>
            <button className={classes.button} onClick={handler}>
              Next
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>
)
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your reply! How could you keep the selection element and the different types of input using this method?

Comment: Added some very rough psuedo code to explain a bit more